# ComposeList not building the expected list of compositions

Tags: list-manipulation

Starting with:

```
In[79]:= a[z_] := z + 1/2
r[z_] := 1/z

tuples = Tuples[{a, r}, 3]

Out[81]= {{a, a, a}, {a, a, r}, {a, r, a}, {a, r, r}, {r, a, a}, {r, 
  a, r}, {r, r, a}, {r, r, r}}
```

I want to get a `ComposeList[]` of each of the element ordered triples over `x`, ending with a list of list of the compositions, e.g. `{{x,a[x],a[a[x]],a[a[a[x]]]},...`

`ComposeList[##, x] & @@@ tuples` does not work. Why, and how should this be written?

That gives me the (erroneous) result:

```
{ComposeList[a, a, a, 3/2], ComposeList[a, a, r, 3/2], 
 ComposeList[a, r, a, 3/2], ComposeList[a, r, r, 3/2], 
 ComposeList[r, a, a, 3/2], ComposeList[r, a, r, 3/2], 
 ComposeList[r, r, a, 3/2], ComposeList[r, r, r, 3/2]}
```

Comment: Might it be that you're after `ComposeList[#, x] & /@ tuples`?

Comment: Precisely. Can you direct me to a best reference (texts and/or links) explaining how to understand such expressions?

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) should be a good start.